# Car insurance during the move

Tags: united-kingdom, car, insurance, relocation

We will be moving from the UK to France mid-March. We are taking our main car (UK registered) with us, for:
1: The travel down there, and
2: The first 2-3 weeks in France to get around, and will purchase a French car then.

I will then drive the UK car back to England to sell it, we don't want to keep it.

On moving day, we are losing our UK address and UK residency.

Our question: will the car be covered in France for these few weeks, under our current UK comprehensive policy (it allows travels in the EU)? I am under the impression that this insurance will be cancelled the day of our move, because we do not have a UK address anymore.

Many thanks in advance for helpful contributions!
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You will have to ask your insurance broker (if you have one), or your insurance company directly.

If you are not insured, you may be able to get a UK based policy through a broker. (I use A-Plan, and am very happy with them.  There are other brokers.)  Alternatively, you may be able to get a policy based in France.